# PHPlist -- not receiving bounced emails

Tags: email, email-bounces, phplist

I am running a Centos 6 VPS and Plesk 11. I am sending a test campaign to my own address and to a fictitious nonsense address and I am receiving the email at my account but I am not receiving any bounces from the nonsense address. My settings in the config.php file are:

```
$message_envelope = 'bounces@mydomain.com';

$bounce_protocol = 'pop';
$bounce_mailbox_host = 'localhost';
$bounce_mailbox_user = 'bounces@mydomain.com';
$bounce_mailbox_password = 'XXXXXX';
```

What's the next step in figuring out the problem? I also tried both variations of the following:

```
$bounce_mailbox_port = "110/pop3/notls";
#$bounce_mailbox_port = "110/pop3";
```

Configuration appears to be correct?

Comment: No, you use either the first choice or the second, which is commented out. The first is recommended, then the second is recommended in case the first doesn't work. Changing which one was used didn't make a difference for me.

Comment: Sorry, being stupid again, too much used to JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out -- after contacting my ISP I discovered I had exceeded my limit on SMTP relays. The bounces are working now -- they're just in the queue.